# Проблема с размером полосы прокрутки для экрана

Tags: javascript

Почему, чтобы выяснить, чему равен размер полосы прокрутки, мы должны сделать вот это:

```js
let w1 = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
let w2 = window.innerWidth;
console.log(w2 - w1);
```

То есть, от **ширины** размера окна браузера отнять **ширину** размера браузера, *включающую в себя прокрутку*. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это от ширины отнять ширину, и получаем размер прокрутки.

Comment: Какие-то определения сомнительные, кажется, что должно быть наоборот. Ширина по внешнему краю минус ширина внутренней области